# When I add a column it said "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: php, mysql

When I add any column in profiles table and then try to edit my profile (bio which is $text in profiles tables) it says:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 1):

That is because you did not specify the column names in your queries

You did

```
insert into profiles 
values (1, 2)
```

But should do

```
insert into profiles (col1, col2)
values (1, 2)
```

That way you can change your table structure and keep your app running.

When you don't specify the columns you want to insert then the DB assumes that you want to fill **all** columns and if you don't provide values for all then your query fails.